# Bootstrap glyphicons have randomly disappeared

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Earlier today, I uploaded a website using bootstrap and the Glyphicons were showing.
When I just logged on, the Glyphicons have now disappeared and look like blank squares or when I look at it on my IPod, they look like IOS emojis.

Can someone please tell me what has happened and how I can fix it?

An example of one of the buttons that contains a Glyphicon is this:

```
<a href="./change_password"><button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Change Password</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably loading Bootstrap as an asset; try loading it through a CDN source instead as a workaround. Put this in your head section of your html file:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded bootstrap because I edited some stuff. If I placed that before the edited bootstrap, will it still show the glythicons and the edited css?

Comment: Well give it a shot first. If it takes over your custom styles, it's very easy to define it via CDN; just go to the stylesheet you are loading in your html and manually override the classes you want. For example: '.navbar {color:red}' etc

Comment: Thank you so much, it didn't override and the icons now work!